# C++ code gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, exc-bad-access

As you can see it's a simple Matrix template.

When I try to run with a basic main function I get a error says "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". I looked to error and read a few things about it but yet I can't find my problem in here. I am pretty newbie and this was my assignment. I missed due date but I want to learn what I am missing...

```
 template <class T>
    class Matrix
    {
    private:
        T** data; // matrix elements stored here
        int rows; // number of rows
        int cols; // number of columns
    public:
        Matrix(int numRows = 0, int numCols = 0); // makes storage allocation but leaves it uninitialized, for 0,0 dont allocate memory
        Matrix(T const* const* inputData, int numRows, int numCols);
        Matrix(const Matrix& rhs);
       ~Matrix();

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& rhs);


    Matrix operator+(const Matrix& rhs) const; // element-wise addition of two matrices
    Matrix operator-(const Matrix& rhs) const; // element-wise subtraction of two matrices
    Matrix operator*(const Matrix& rhs) const; // multiplication of two matrices, dot product


    T operator()(int r, int c) const; // returns the element value at row r and column c
    T& operator()(int r, int c); // returns reference of the element value at row r and column c

     int getRows() const; // returns the number of rows
     int getCols() const; // returns the number of columns

    void print() const; // prints the matrix with each column element separated by a tab and each row element in a new line print a newline after the last row
};





#include <iostream>


//parameter constructor
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int _rows, int _cols) {


    rows = _rows;
    cols = _cols;
    T** data;
    data=new T *[_rows];
    for (int i=0; i< _rows; i++) {
        data[i]=new T [_cols];
    }

}



//copy constructor

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>& rhs) {

    data=new T*;
    rows = rhs.getRows();
    cols = rhs.getCols();

}

//destructor

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix() {}

//assignment operator

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator=(const Matrix<T>& rhs) {
    if (&rhs == this)
        return *this;

    int new_rows = rhs.getRows();
    int new_cols = rhs.getCols();

    data=new T *(new_rows);
    for (int i=0; i<rhs.size(); i++) {
        data[i].resize(new_cols);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<new_rows; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<new_cols; j++) {
            data[i][j] = rhs(i, j);
        }
    }
    rows = new_rows;
    cols = new_cols;

    return *this;

}

//matematical operands
//1. addition

template<typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix& rhs) const {

    Matrix<T> result(*this);
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            result(i,j) = this->data[i][j] + rhs(i,j);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

//2.subtraction

template<typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator-(const Matrix& rhs) const {
    Matrix result(rows, cols);

    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            result(i,j) = this->data[i][j] - rhs(i,j);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

//3.multiplication

template<typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator*(const Matrix& rhs) const {
    int rows = rhs.getRows();
    int cols = rhs.getCols();
    Matrix result(rows, cols);

    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            for (int k=0; k<rows; k++) {
                result(i,j) = this->data[i][k] * rhs(k,j);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

//access the elements

template<typename T>
T Matrix<T>::operator()(int r, int c) const{
    return this->data[r][c];
}

//returns the reference value of element

template<typename T>
T& Matrix<T>::operator()(int r, int c){
    return this->data[r][c];
}

//number of rows
template<typename T>
int Matrix<T>::getRows() const {
    return this->rows;
}

//number of cols
template<typename T>
int Matrix<T>::getCols() const{
    return this->cols;
}

//printing
template <typename T>
void Matrix<T>::print() const{
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            std::cout<<this->data[i][j]<<"/t";
            std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That _you_ can't debug it, doesn't mean your program can't be debugged. But SO isn't an online debugging service unfortunately.

Comment: I am not here for debuging service. I asked so maybe some can tell me where I do wrong. What I am missing. After that maybe I can debug it.

Comment: Sorry, no. You debug first, and ask afterwards. What's actually hindering you stepping through your code line by line?

Comment: Perhaps ask yourself what does the `T*` you've allocated in your copy-constructor with `data=new T*;` actually *point-to* ? Or maybe the *local variable* declaration of `data` in the regular constructor that supersedes the member variable `data` that you likely want to properly initialier should be looked at. As it stands now `Matrix<T>::Matrix(int _rows, int _cols)` is both a memory-leak factory and leaves the *member* `data` uninitialized.

Comment: Try to learn about debugging first then. Step trough a hello world program. With a suitable IDE this is pretty simple, but when you build at the command line you need to include the proper options for debugging info (especially for g++/gdb)

Comment: You've got to be joking? This code is far too long. You obviously _are_ asking us to debug it for you so it's strange that you claim otherwise!

Comment: All I was asking where to look and it's answered by @WhozCraig .Thanks. For those who blame me for using stack overflow as a debugging facility it's your point of view, I respect that. But that wasn't my angle on this topic. I am not a programmer (yet) and I am trying to learn. I can't get my out of this error and asked. Like you done far long ago...

Comment: @CgtyKy You have a lot of issues with the code.  One being that your copy constructor is totally broken.  What you should do is take all of that code in your assignment operator and move it to your copy constructor.  Then implement the assignment operator in terms of the copy constructor.

Comment: @CgtyKy BTW, you *must* fix your copy constructor, else your class is  useless.  Without a working copy constructor, your overloaded `+`,`-`, and other operators that return a `Matrix<T>` object will not work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks. I am working on it. As a beginner I am truly grateful for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see too many errors in your code related to handling of dynamic memory allocation for `data`. Most of them can be fixed/easily remedied by using `std::vector` for the private data.

Instead of:

```
T** data; // matrix elements stored here
int rows; // number of rows
int cols; // number of columns
```

use:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> data;
```